# i am unable to load js file in page internal server error occure in network tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[enter image description here][1]    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    // here iam given relative path of javascript
    // i think there is nothing wrong in path
        <script  src="../../public/assets/app/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../public/assets/app/js/myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="login">
        <p>User Name :<br>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
            <span id="email"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            Password :<br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <span id="pass"></span>
        </p>
        <br><br>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="status"></p>

    </body>
    </html>

These are the errors in network tab in my browser:

[![when i refresh my page to face such error iam unable to resolve it][2]][2]
```

// these are the snapshot it think every thing is ok
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ2Fj.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI3Rc.png

Comment: This is an error on your server, not in your HTML code. Check your server's log files

Comment: i think this error occur due to undefined route http://rehanschool/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js i am using slim 3 framework

Comment: Then most likely the paths to your static resources are incorrect, they do look strange: *../../public/assets/app/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js* → you'll have to figure out what the correct path is